# creating a strobe, flashing background using handlers

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to make a strobe effect in the background of my app. I read that handlers would work the best, but I'm just not sure how to apply them. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810705/how-do-i-make-a-layout-background-flashing-in-android)

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    final int DELAY = 100;

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {


        RelativeLayout fondo = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.fondo);

        ColorDrawable f = new ColorDrawable(0xff00ff00);
        ColorDrawable f2 = new ColorDrawable(0xffff0000);
        ColorDrawable f3 = new ColorDrawable(0xff0000ff);
        ColorDrawable f4 = new ColorDrawable(0xff0000ff);

        AnimationDrawable a = new AnimationDrawable();
        a.addFrame(f, DELAY);
        a.addFrame(f2, DELAY);
        a.addFrame(f3, DELAY);
        a.addFrame(f4, DELAY);
        a.setOneShot(false);

        fondo.setBackgroundDrawable(a); // This method is deprecated in API 16
        // fondo.setBackground(a); // Use this method if you're using API 16
        a.start();
     }
     return true;
}
```

What do I need to do to fix this? and is there a way to do this without handlers?

```
 package com.example.converter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class Savannah extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_savannah);
    r.setOnTouchListener=(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            final int DELAY = 100;

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                RelativeLayout fondo = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_savannah);

                ColorDrawable f = new ColorDrawable(0xff00ff00);
                ColorDrawable f2 = new ColorDrawable(0xffff0000);
                ColorDrawable f3 = new ColorDrawable(0xff0000ff);
                ColorDrawable f4 = new ColorDrawable(0xff0000ff);

                AnimationDrawable a = new AnimationDrawable();
                a.addFrame(f, DELAY);
                a.addFrame(f2, DELAY);
                a.addFrame(f3, DELAY);
                a.addFrame(f4, DELAY);
                a.setOneShot(false);

                fondo.setBackgroundDrawable(a); // This method is deprecated
                                                // in API
                                                // 16
                // fondo.setBackground(a); // Use this method if you're
                // using API 16
                a.start();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

this is what i have, but the seontouch listener is flagging errors as is the ontouch view view motion event.

Comment: What Happens when you run the code? Does it throw an exception or does it just not work?

Comment: the onTouch command and fondo flag as errors

Comment: So it still runs, but it doesn't strobe?

Comment: I tried your code but to activate the animation i use the `onTouch()` event of the relative layout, and it worked perfectly. So what is your problem?

Comment: yes it runs but wont strobe, and how do i add the ontouch to the layout?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that i tested my self and working perfectly:

```
RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
    r.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            final int DELAY = 100;

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                RelativeLayout fondo = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);

                ColorDrawable f = new ColorDrawable(0xff00ff00);
                ColorDrawable f2 = new ColorDrawable(0xffff0000);
                ColorDrawable f3 = new ColorDrawable(0xff0000ff);
                ColorDrawable f4 = new ColorDrawable(0xff0000ff);

                AnimationDrawable a = new AnimationDrawable();
                a.addFrame(f, DELAY);
                a.addFrame(f2, DELAY);
                a.addFrame(f3, DELAY);
                a.addFrame(f4, DELAY);
                a.setOneShot(false);

                fondo.setBackgroundDrawable(a); // This method is deprecated
                                                // in API
                                                // 16
                // fondo.setBackground(a); // Use this method if you're
                // using API 16
                a.start();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: so i tried your code and it doesn't seem to work, eclipse tells me to remove the @override and change boolean to void, and the findViewById field wont recognize my class.

Comment: and when i change these things it runs but doesnt do anything different

Comment: First thing you have to go in project properties where you have to select java compiler 1.6. The second thing `findViewById`  happens when you are using your code inside some fragment. if yes then use some thing like this `view.findViewById` .wher `view` is your current inflated layout in the current fragment.

Comment: One thing i forget to mention here is that the above code i have written in `Activity` `onCreate()` method.

Comment: so above you mentioned that you added the ontouch comand to the layout, im kinda new so could you explain that more

Comment: To test this code just copy and paste it into the `onCreate()` method of activity.

Comment: so im still getting errors, i posted my code above, would you take a look?

Comment: I have updated your code now test it, as your code have two missing lines 1 `constructor for super class` 2 `setting the content view`