# how to change boolean on touch to something like view

Tags: android, view, background, touch

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    final int DELAY = 100;

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {


        RelativeLayout fondo = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);

        ColorDrawable f = new ColorDrawable(0xff00ff00);
        ColorDrawable f2 = new ColorDrawable(0xffff0000);
        ColorDrawable f3 = new ColorDrawable(0xff0000ff);
        ColorDrawable f4 = new ColorDrawable(0xff0000ff);

        AnimationDrawable a = new AnimationDrawable();
        a.addFrame(f, DELAY);
        a.addFrame(f2, DELAY);
        a.addFrame(f3, DELAY);
        a.addFrame(f4, DELAY);
        a.setOneShot(false);

        fondo.setBackgroundDrawable(a); // This method is deprecated in API 16
        // fondo.setBackground(a); // Use this method if you're using API 16
        a.start();
     }
     return true;
}
```

i want to instead of the above ontouch boolean, my background to change color when viewed and not touched.like press a button go to a new layout and then without touching the screen to start flashing

Comment: Your question is not clear... what action do you want to perform once touched?

Comment: well..actually i wanna replace on touch, i don't want to touch the screen ,i want to open a layout and see my background flashing,it just happened to workout out that way,

Answer (score 1):

Still need to be a bit more clear for us to help, not entirely sure what you are attempting to do.

If I understand correctly you want to press one button and then open a new layout where the screen is flashing?

Comment: What I suggest you do is something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810705/how-do-i-make-a-layout-background-flashing-in-android?rq=1

Comment: my idea is from there, and i am looking for that something,although as i said, i don't wanna touch the screen

Comment: Instead of running the loop inside of the boolean onTouch, simply create it inside of a method and call that method within the onCreate of your activity you wish to have a flashing screen.

Comment: if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {, u mean something like that, right, but nothing happens,still haven't solved my problem ://